# Displaying the logs of mongo container is going wrong

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm creating a mongo container using this command

`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --net mongo-network --name mongodb mongo`

, then executing this command to see its logs `docker logs mangodb`

i'm getting [this reult](https://ideone.com/HyawXU)

i cant understand if mongodb is successfully created or not

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the logs. Also, please paste the text instead of using an image

Comment: okey i already edited it, u can find full log

Comment: Looks like the database starts successfully and clients make connections. Thought it also looks like there are things that might need addressing like low rlimits configured and very old client driver version

Comment: which driver? i already downloaded the latest